# GCC Statement Expression Issue

Tags: c, gcc

I just read about Statement Expressions Extension in GCC, and I found some unexpected behavior when using it.

Please observe this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char* res1 = ({
                        char arr[] ={'h', 'e', '\0'}; // was char *arr[]
                        arr[0] = 'x';
                        char* ptr = arr;
                        ptr;
                 });


    char* res2 = ({
                        char arr[] ={'h', 'e', '\0'}; // was char *arr[]
                        arr[0] = 'X';
                        char* ptr = arr;
                        ptr;
                 });

    printf ("%s %p\n", res1, res1);
    printf ("%s %p\n", res2, res2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
X 0x7fff93098160
X 0x7fff93098160
```

I noticing that, the variables `arr` in first block and `arr` in second block taking the same memory address.

Why that happening??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both occurrences of `arr` are array objects with automatic storage duration; they're local to the enclosing block `{ ... }` within the statement expression.

Each statement expression grabs the address of that local variable; that address is saved in `res1` and res2`and used *after* the end of the block, when the object`arr` *no longer exists*.

This is the same problem as a function returning the address of a local variable.  The address becomes invalid when the variable ceases to exist, and the program's behavior is undefined.

So don't do that.

Comment: So sorry, I've copy and paste an incorrect code, I've modified it.

Comment: I've edited my answer, since the corrected code is now in the question and is no longer needed here.

Comment: Is there any reference documentation to confirm that the storage duration is automatic , and not something else such as the end of the full-expression?   [Came up in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486940/declare-an-array-in-gcc-statement-expression-and-return-a-pointer-to-it). The gcc official doc page didn't say.

Comment: @M.M: I don't think the gcc documentation needs to specify it. The array objects are defined inside a compound statement without `static`, so they have automatic storage duration by the language rules. The fact that the compound statement happens to be part of a gcc-specific expression statement shouldn't affect that, and I think it's safe to assume that it doesn't in the absence of an explicit statement to the contrary.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, the scope of variables defined in statement expressions is just those statement expressions themselves. That is, when `res1` is initialized, the array is already out of scope, and the pointer points to unallocated memory. The array in the second statement expression happens to occupy the same memory. It's actually not much different from the following code:

```
char* res1;
{
  char arr[] ={'h', 'e', '\0'};
  arr[0] = 'x';
  char* ptr = arr;
  res1 = ptr;
}

char* res2;
{
  char arr[] ={'h', 'e', '\0'};
  arr[0] = 'X';
  char* ptr = arr;
  res2 = ptr;
}

printf ("%s %p\n", res1, res1);
printf ("%s %p\n", res2, res2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Both arrays are local to the statement expressions, and the memory they occupy can be reused after the end of the expression. In this case, it *is* reused.

If you would access or use these pointer's values, you would be invoking undefined behaviour, so their equality is of no consequence.