# Declare an array in gcc statement-expression and return a pointer to it?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I have thought about it.
And this is the code:

```
#define IP_VAL(id) ({ \
    char ip[32] = {0}; \
    sprintf(ip,"192.168.0.%d",id&0xff); \
    (char *)ip; \
})
```

It really works, but I wonder whether problems will be caused by the macro?

I used it like this:

```
function(IP_VAL(id));
```

But I am not sure it is absolutely OK. Is the `ip[32]` out of the action scope?

Thank you very much for editing my question : )

I have tested the simple example like this:

```
main(){
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    a = b;
    a = ({
            int c = 3;
            c;
        });
    a = ({
            int d = 4;
            d;
        });
    a = ({
            int c = 5;
            c;
        });
    ({
        int c = 6;
        c;
    });
    ({
        int c = 7;
        c;
    });
    ({
        int c = 8;
        c;
    });
}
```

And objdump it:

```
080483ed <main>:
 80483ed:   55                      push   %ebp
 80483ee:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483f0:   83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
 80483f3:   c7 45 e0 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x20(%ebp)
 80483fa:   c7 45 e4 02 00 00 00    movl   $0x2,-0x1c(%ebp)
 8048401:   8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%ebp),%eax
 8048404:   89 45 e0                mov    %eax,-0x20(%ebp)
 8048407:   c7 45 e8 03 00 00 00    movl   $0x3,-0x18(%ebp)
 804840e:   8b 45 e8                mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
 8048411:   89 45 e0                mov    %eax,-0x20(%ebp)
 8048414:   c7 45 ec 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x4,-0x14(%ebp)
 804841b:   8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
 804841e:   89 45 e0                mov    %eax,-0x20(%ebp)
 8048421:   c7 45 f0 05 00 00 00    movl   $0x5,-0x10(%ebp)
 8048428:   8b 45 f0                mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
 804842b:   89 45 e0                mov    %eax,-0x20(%ebp)
 804842e:   c7 45 f4 06 00 00 00    movl   $0x6,-0xc(%ebp)
 8048435:   c7 45 f8 07 00 00 00    movl   $0x7,-0x8(%ebp)
 804843c:   c7 45 fc 08 00 00 00    movl   $0x8,-0x4(%ebp)
 8048443:   c9                      leave  
 8048444:   c3                      ret
```

So I think the 'c' and the 'd' is just like 'a' and 'b',they are the variables in the stack of 'main()'. The difference is their scopes. And in the example, every 'c' has different addresses.

I think the macro 'IP_VAL' works, but I do not know the gcc compile option will affect it or not ?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one or the other, not both.

Comment: It certainly isn't ok. Use a function.

Comment: **Macros are not functions!**

Comment: I removed the C++ tag, since you're asking for C and your code doesn't show any C++. C and C++ are different languages

Comment: Also note that [*compound statements*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) is a GCC extension. It's not a standard C functionality.

Comment: The gcc documentation doesn't say what the lifetime of `ip` is (could be either the statement-expression, or the enclosing full-expression)

Comment: No this is absolutely not OK.

Comment: `id&0xFF` should be `(id)&0xFF`

Comment: @2501 what function would you suggest exactly (to enable the usage `func( IP_VAL(id) )`)

Comment: [Here is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865661/gcc-statement-expression-issue) but there aren't any satisfactory answers

Comment: @DavidBowling the function presumably expects a string containing an IP address

Comment: [This example](http://ideone.com/mg374A) suggests that perhaps the duration is the full-expression (making the code OK) - if the duration was the block, then it could have used the same address for both

Comment: Don't rely on it. See this: [one](http://ideone.com/KmuaRV) [two](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a0f5481c326e78a)

Comment: @n.m. those are both consistent with the duration being the full-expression. Can you produce any example in C with output that shows the duration is not the full-expression?

Comment: @M.M you are righ, the example is incorrect, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2223f3cefc8b5df8) is a correct (I think) one.

Comment: @n.m. OK. I wonder why gcc on coliru differs from gcc on ideone. In any case it shows that it's not safe to use.

Comment: @M.M Different versions I think (or maybe ideone's one is actually a clang, [see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63a856bed9bf893f))

Answer (score 2):

This is not standard C but a gcc extension. It is not being used safely.

The lifetime of the `ip` array is restricted to the scope it is declared in. You are returning a pointer into this array to the outsides of the statement-expression, where the array no longer exists. Some people suggest that the lifetime is the duration of the full expression, but nothing in GCC documentation seems to support this claim. Dereferencing this pointer may result in anything. It appears to work by sheer luck.

Declaring the array as `static` will fix the problem, but then a static local array lets you write a simple function which doesn't depend on a gcc extension.

Another way to cope with the problem is as follows:

```
#define IP_VAL(id) \
    ( \
     ( \
      { \
       struct { char ip[32]; } p; \
       sprintf (p.ip, "192.168.0.%d", id&0xff); \
       p; \
      } \
     ).ip \
    )
```

This version doesn't have any pointers that point to any potentially expired local variables.

Comment: This is one is nice, but I can not understand the essential difference between two examples.

Comment: One version has (1) a scoped variable and (2) a pointer to that variable that is accessed outside of the scope. The other one has (1) a temporary array inside a temporary struct that decays to a pointer to its first element (2) said pointer accessed while the temporary is still alive. To better visualize this, rewrite both macros as functions. One returns a pointer to its local variable, the other returns a struct by value.

Comment: Why not simply:

#define IP_VAL(id) ({ \
    char ip[32] = {0}; \
    sprintf(ip,"192.168.0.%d",id&0xff); \
    ip; \
})

I'd assume that this returns array by value, which is of type char[32] and hence is safe to use in the parent expression

Comment: @user377178 You cannot pass an array by value, there's no such thing. Struct is needed precisely because of that.

Comment: I can see now this. Thanks. My experiments indicate that gcc does preserve the buffers even when passing through pointer. Better safe then sorry though.